# Difference between #DEBUG and #DEVELOPMENT_BUILD in Unity?

Tags: unity, c#, build-process, release

I've seen these two special compilation macros in our code base, What's the difference between `#Debug` and `#DEVELOPEMENT_BUILD` in Unity? What's the main purpose of using each?

```
#if DEBUG
Debug.Log("DEBUG");
#endif

#if DEVELOPMENT_BUILD
Debug.Log("DEVELOPMENT_BUILD");
#endif
```

Answer (score 4):

From [these](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PlatformDependentCompilation.html)  docs:

> You use the DEVELOPMENT_BUILD #define to identify whether your script is running in a player which was built with the “Development Build” option enabled.

On the other hand, DEBUG doesn't exist.

Comment: Unity may not have felt like documenting it, but DEBUG certainly exists, and has since at least Unity 3.x.

Comment: @piojo If it's not documented, it shouldn't be used, as it may be removed on future versions without notice.

Comment: @TomTsagk Normally I would agree with you, but I think this case is an exception. I've reported a documentation omission bug to Unity, so we'll see what they think.

Answer (score 1):

In my testing with Unity 2018 (and it is different in Unity 2020 according to the comments), I found DEBUG is true in the editor and during development builds (it is true during the build so the code is compiled into the build). DEBUG is not true during release builds.

DEVELOPMENT_BUILD is never true in the editor except during development builds (so the code is only runs in development builds, never in the editor). I'm not sure whether editor callbacks (surrounded with `#if DEVELOPMENT_BUILD`) would run while compiling a development build.

This preprocessor directive is [not documented](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PlatformDependentCompilation.html). I reported the omission as a documentation bug, but they may not consider it their responsibility to document .NET conventions.

Comment: DEBUG isn't in the Unity documentation because it's not a Unity feature, [it's a standard C#/.NET define used when the code has been compiled in debug configuration rather than release](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/preprocessor-directives/preprocessor-if). Note that Unity 2020 uses release configuration in the Editor unless you deliberately switch to debug, so "DEBUG is true in the editor" is not universally true.

Comment: @DMGregory Thanks, I adjusted my answer.